# How to create a parameters based SQL server query using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am using the following code.

```
import sqlalchemy as sq
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns

server = 'ourServer'
database = 'ourdatabase'
driver = 'SQL Server'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
database_connection= f'mssql://{username}:{password}@{server}/{database}?driver={driver}'

engine = sq.create_engine(database_connection)
connection = engine.connect()

account_id = '111111111'

x= pd.read_sql_query("select * from tablename where AccountID =?, account_id" , connection)
```

When I run the above code it throws this error.

> DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

How to pass parameter for SQL query condition?

Comment: This seems to be covered in the [read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) documentation. Have you tried: `x= pd.read_sql_query("select * from tablename where AccountID =?" , connection, params=(account_id) )`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Missing a comma to make it a tuple? `params=(account_id,)`

Comment: Thank you so much @GordThompson. It is working with tuple.

Comment: Also thanks to @AlwaysLearning for your quick response.